# My Ubuntu screen is in full zoom and it is all white screen

Tags: zooming, white-screen

I went to settings in my laptop which is running on Ubuntu and went to universal access. Then I clicked in zoom option and my laptop screen went full white.

What can I do now to fix this?

Comment: What did you click exactly? Did you try simply rebooting your laptop?

Comment: It sounds like you might be in full zoom.  You can press alt+super+8 to disable the zoom, or alt+super+- to zoom out.  That might take several steps to get to a reasonable zoom level

Comment: #FloT ... Settings+universal access + zoom option + color then I full the high, low and contrast bar then turn on the zoom.

Comment: Charles Green - I pressed alt+super+-. I think it work but still  I am facing white screen.

Comment: You may have to press it several times to unzoom, if you have zoomed way in.

Answer (score 2):

from the comments, it is observed that you have changed these two

1. Bightness to High
2. Contrast to High

[image]

[image]

Assuming you are with GNOME

these two changes can be controlled with command line,

the default values are,

for brightness:

```
org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier brightness-red 0.0
org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier brightness-green 0.0
org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier brightness-blue 0.0
```

for contrast:

```
org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier contrast-red 0.0
org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier contrast-green 0.0
org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier contrast-blue 0.0
```

So, logon to any console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 or F3 or F4 etc..

then run the below commands to reset the values to default and then reboot.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier brightness-green 0
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier brightness-blue 0
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier brightness-red 0
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier contrast-green 0
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier contrast-blue 0
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier contrast-red 0
```

[image]